# WSO2 Carbon/API/DSS/ESB - Docker Restart

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

What is the correct way to restart WSO2 products from the command line when running in a Docker container?

Each management console provides a 'Forced Restart' function, which gracefully restarts the product. However, I've not been able to determine what this function actually does.

I've attempted to run wso2server.sh restart from within the container, but this does not restart the ENTRYPOINT process in Docker. It has also crashed my containers on several occasions.

Comment: Restarting the whole container will do the Job IMO

Answer (score 0):

Forced restart and gracefully restart also should work. However you can restart the docker container for your purpose.For more information on running wso2 products on docker you can follow [this](http://thilina.piyasundara.org/2014/05/run-wso2-products-in-docker-container.html) guide.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Forced restart works from the GUI. I would like to mimic this functionality from the command line?